# AngularJS - Google Map Markers Removal

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, google-maps

Cant find an solutions how to do this with `uiGmapGoogleMapApi`.Since `google` object is not imported, cant use regular solutions.

My markers update via:

```
$scope.change_type = function(val) {
        var markers = [];
        $scope.eventMarkers = markers
        var events = Events.venues(val.type)
        for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
            event = events[i]
            markers.push(createMarker(i,event))
        }
        $timeout(function(){$scope.eventMarkers = markers}, 100)
```

My temp work around was to create timeout long enough for it to update before pushing new, but this is not a real solution and doesnt work too well on an actual device. Pushing empty array of markers also didnt work. Seems like I have to use `.setMap(null)` but cant find any documentation on how and where.

Comment: At what event do you intend to remove the markers from the map?

Comment: its supposed to refresh the map when I change input. I first push saying, there should be none on the map via empty array and then load new ones. That doesnt work out as planned though

Answer (score 2):

```js
// Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
function clearMarkers() {
  setAllMap(null);

// Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
function deleteMarkers() {
  clearMarkers();
  markers = [];
```